# Is making objects of two classes member of each other a bad practice?

Tags: oop, object, unity-game-engine, member

Here's a bare minimum pseodo-code of what I use:

```
class A{
    //other variables
    B b;

    void delayedPartnerInit(B b){
        this.b=b;
    }
}

class B{
    //some other variables

    A a;

    void delayedPartnerInit(A a){
        this.a=a;
    }
}
```

I could make it into a single class but certain members(not shown here) of A are needed to exist before data about B. In other words, objects of A and B are instanced at different times but need reference of each other's variables once both set of variables are available.

The question is there a better way to do this? Am I missing some basic concept of programming?
Though I am currently working on C#, I have had this thought many times before when working with other languages too.

***Update***: I am using this in Unity game engine where B is Unity C# script. Since Unity doesn't allow us create scripts without adding it to something I need 2 classes. I get certain data(A's data) earliar which needs processing.

Didn't mention this earlier because I asked it as a generic question.

**Note before closing as duplicate**: I checked similar questions but found only specific questions that caused issues to authors who tried to do what I am doing. My question is whether it is a bad practice.

Comment: Typically try to avoid tightly coupled classes such as this.

Comment: `Since Unity doesn't allow us create scripts without adding it to something I need 2 classes.` This is a very vague claim. Ofcourse you can create instances of classes without attaching them to a certain `GameObject` if this is what you mean .. it applies only to classes of type `Component`. Any `static` class e.g. would simply exist for the entire session. Also within a MonoBehaviour you can use `new` to create an instance of a "normal" class at any time. One could even be a subclass of the other ... so maybe you should try to describe your exact usecase and add your actual code ...

Answer (score 0):

Tightly coupled classes are generally bad practice:

- Changes in one class lead to changes in another.
- You cannot test one of classes without creating (or mocking) another one. Which in your case creates circular dependency.
- Both classes depend on each other's implementations, not abstractions.
- Harder for other persons (or yourself half a year later) to understand and reason about first class logic without inspecting second class as well.

---

> Since Unity doesn't allow us create scripts without adding it to something I need 2 classes. I get certain data(A's data) earliar which needs processing

MVC pattern for Unity provides useful trick for decoupling monobehaviours:

```
interface ISomeObjectView {
    event Action OnUpdate;
    event Action Destroyed;
    event Action TriggerEntered;
    void SetTransform(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
    void AddForce(Vector3 force);
    // Other methods or events you need to expose:
    // MouseOver, OnFixedUpdate, Move() or SetScale(), ...
}
```

MonoBehaviour itself does not contain any logic, it simply invokes events and uses incoming values:

```
public void SetTransform(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
{
    // Params validation
    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
}

private void Update()
    => OnUpdate?.Invoke();
```

MonoBehaviour logic must be moved to your data class or new controller class. Now your data class simply links itself to provided interface events and methods without circular dependencies. Monobehaviour does not require any references to other classes, it simply provides methods to manipulate itself and events to catch input.

This trick helps in several ways:

- MonoBehaviour doesn't depend on anything and doesn't require any references to other classes.
- Your data/logic classes doesn't require ant special knowledge about monobehaviours, only provided interface.
- You can have several implementations for interface, switching different views depending on situation.
- Easy to test, easy to mock.
- You can move all the "Unity stuff" inside MonoBehaviour and write all related classes on pure C#. If you want to.

Please note that using `event Action` is **not conventional way** to deal with events! I think it's very convenient, but I'd suggest to use conventional `EventHandler` (UnityEvents is another option that might suit your needs).

---

**Update**: an example of simple MVC.

Consider the following `Player` controller:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerInfo {

    // Values configurable via inspector
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float damage = 15;
    [SerializeField] private Player playerPrefab;

    public float Speed => speed;
    public float JumpHeight => jumpHeight ;
    public float Damage => damage;

    private Player playerInstance;

    public void InitializePlayer() {
        playerInstance = Instantiate(playerPrefab);
        playerInstance.Info = this;
    }

    public void TeleportTo(Vector3 newPosition) {
        playerInstance.transform.position = newPosition;
    }
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public PlayerInfo Info { get; set; }
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * info.JumpHeight);
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.AddForce(movement * info.Speed);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        var enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
            enemy.TakeHit(info.Damage);
    }
}
```

There you go. PlayerInfo is created before Player. PlayerInfo references Player and Player references PlayerInfo. Player is used to move gameobject and attack enemies, PlayerInfo contains required info. What can we do here?

First, Rewrite MonoBehaviour without any logic:

```
public class PlayerView : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Events for future subscription.
    public event Action OnUpdate;
    public event TriggerEntered<Collider>;

    // Simple initialization of required components.
    private void Awake() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Unity methods doing nothing but invoking events.
    private void Update() {
        OnUpdate?.Invoke();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        TriggerEntered?.Invoke(other);
    }

    // We still need a method to move our player, right?
    public void Move(Vector3 direction) {
        rb.AddForce(direction);
    }

    public void SetPosition(Vector3 position) {
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Now you need class containing data about player:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerModel {

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float damage = 15;

    public float Speed => speed;
    public float JumpHeight => jumpHeight ;
    public float Damage => damage;
}
```

Now we need a way to tie those two together:

```
public class PlayerController {

    private readonly PlayerModel model;
    private readonly PlayerView view;

    public PlayerController(PlayerModel model, PlayerView view) {
        // Validate values here.

        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        // Linking logic to events.
        view.OnUpdate += Move;
        view.TriggerEntered += Attack;
    }

    // Actual logic moved here.
    private void Move() {
        Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")
            movement += Vector3.up * model.JumpHeight;
        movement += new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * model.Speed;
        view.Move(movement);
    }

    private void Attack(Collider other) {
        var enemy = other.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
            enemy.TakeHit(model.Damage);
    }

    // Method from PlayerInfo to set player position without actual movements.
    public void MoveTo(Vector3 position) {
        view.SetPosition(position);
    }
}
```

Now you have 3 classes instead of 2, but model and view classes are very simple and do not require any dependencies. All the work is done by Controller class, which receives other two pieces and ties them together.

It becomes even better when interfaces are introduced in addition to classes: `IPlayerModel`, `IPlayerView`, `IPlayerController`.

You might think that it would be easier to create single class instead of three linked classes, but in the long run you will thank yourself for using this pattern: view and model are extremely simple, easy to read, easy to check for errors, easy to expand with new functionality. Single class, on the other hand, will quickly grow to hundreds of lines and become a nightmare to test and expand.

I strongly recommend [this article](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3092) with more complicated examples of MVC.

Comment: But don't we need to write the logic for all Unity related methods/events ourself(`MonoBehaviour logic must be moved to your data class or new controller class.`)? I wanted to keep my data in an class that's independent of Unity. Guess it's not possible.
`Now your data class simply links itself to provided interface events and methods without circular dependencies.`
How exactly do I do this?

Comment: @Anutrix like I showed in example, MonoBehaviour class has `OnUpdate` event, which invoked each `Update()`. You can attach any logic you need to that event: `view.OnUpdate += MyUpdateMethod()`. As long as method is attached to event it will be invoked each frame. Basically you move all methods outside of MonoBehaviour and then link them via events.

Comment: So you want me to make an interface that inherits MonoBehaviour and calls the each of respective functions in the data class?

Comment: Please advice. I really need this to work. Also, won't doing what I just said have negative affect on performance since there will be calls to update() every frame?

Comment: @Anutrix `there will be calls to update() every frame?` Well, yeah. But keep in mind that if you don't need to forward Update events to other scripts - then just don't use `void Update()` and `event Action OnUpdate`. Think of it this way: if your monobehaviour has `Update()` with logic inside it, then move logic outside and provide `public event` for subscription. If you do not have `Update` logic - then do nothing. Same goes for other unity functions - use events like `OnAwake`, `MouseOver`, `TriggerEntered` only if you have logic inside those methods. (Also I updated my post with examples)